# What does "8(3)A" mean on a relay spec sheet?

Tags: electrical, heating

In the specs for this heating controller (http://www.ecr-nederland.nl/files/lae_bediening_ac1-2w_en_de.pdf) the relays have a capacity of 8(3)A (top-right). What does this mean? 8A/3A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't be 100% without a relay part number or datasheet -- but most commonly, that type of specification would be 8A switching a resistive load (say a small heating element), and 3A switching an inductive load (say a fan motor).

Solid-state inputs and relay coils generally don't draw enough current to be a problem.

Comment: Makes sense, cheers!